# How to change a column in ListView (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, listview

Currently, I have solved this issue as follows:

```
Public Sub SelectedDate(ByVal FiD&, Optional Datum As Date)
    Dim Item As ListItem

    For Each Item In Me.ListView1.ListItems
        If Item.text = FiD And Datum <> "00:00:00" Then
            Item.ListSubItems(4) = Datum
            Exit For
        ElseIf Item.text = FiD And Item.Checked Then
            Item.Checked = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I assume that there is a better solution to find the item in the ListView and to change a value in a column of this item.

Do anyone have an idea?

Comment: Sounds like a great question for code review. SO is typically reserved for issues (e.g. not working) in code.

Comment: @RyanWildry What do you mean exactly? Do you need more code?

Comment: Post this question to Code Review. It's an optimization question.